# Column locking in innodb?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, database-administration

I know this sounds weird, but apparently one of my columns is locked.

```
select * from table where type_id = 1 and updated_at < '2010-03-14' limit 1;

select * from table where type_id = 3 and updated_at < '2010-03-14' limit 10;
```

The first one would not finish running even in a few hours, while the second one completes smoothly. the only difference is the type_id between the 2 queries.

A bit of background, the first statement screwed up before which I had to kill manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you do not have an index on (type_id, updated_at) and your table is rather large.

Creating the index should fix the problem:

```
CREATE INDEX type_updated_idx ON table (type_id, updated_at);
```

Assuming, you have enough permissions to make data definition statements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running an `ANALYZE TABLE` on the affected table?

You may want to consider converting over to MyISAM tables, as InnoDB tables have [problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html) and restrictions.

Comment: Just ran it - looks perfectly ok. Thanks for the read on innodb restrictions tho!

Comment: Innodb has row level locking, that means if 10 of 1 billion rows are being updated you can access all rows except those 10.

Myisam has table level locking, that means if you update 10 of 1 billion rows you'll not be able to access ANY of the 10 billion rows until the update is finished.

I've stopped using myisam totally and never regreted.

Answer (score 0):

A column cannot be locked - but an index range can. `Show innodb status` will normally tell you after which active transaction yours is waiting.

Comment: thanks! it says "Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation" - any idea why?